# CSS3+jQuery image transform

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

I'm building a image transformer with CSS3 and jQuery that will enlarge the photo hovered and reduces the width of the photo to right of the hovered photo. Everything looking good except from the fourth photo, that won't take place inside the container at some scenarios and will instead break line, which I don't wan't it to do.

How should I write my code to make this work fine?

http://tinyurl.com/ncy2lqv

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to `.start-images-container`
and change `float:left;` in `.start-image` to `display:inline-block;`.

This will result in the desired effect, however inline-block; creates unwanted space between the images. See this article for information. http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

tldr; remove the spaces between the div's